# Program got stuck , not printing output

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. And I am trying to play with character array in C++. So, I have written this code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Main Function
int main()
{
   //Variable declaration
   char First[30];
   char Middle[30];
   char Last[40];
   //Array to store all names
   char Name[70];

   //Loop variables
   int i = 0, j = 0;

   //Reading all the name
   cout << "Enter First name: ";
   cin >> First;

   cout << "Enter Middle name: ";
   cin >> Middle;

   cout << "Enter Last name: ";
   cin >> Last;

   //Copies all characters of Last name to fourth array
   while (Last[i] != '\0')
   {
       Name[j] = Last[i];
       i++;
       j++;
   }
   //placing a comma in the fourth array and adding a space
   Name[j] = ',';
   j++;
   Name[j] = ' ';
   j++;

    cout<<"Hello1\n";

   //Copies all characters of First name to fourth array
   i = 0;
   while (First[i] != '\0');
   {
       Name[j] = First[i];
       i++;
       j++;
   }
   //Add a space
   Name[j] = ' ';
   j++;


    cout<<"Hello2\n";

   //Copies all characters of Middle name to fourth array
   i = 0;
   while (Middle[i] != '\0');
   {
       Name[j] = Middle[i];
       i++;
       j++;
   }
   Name[j] = '\0';
   //Display the fourth array
   cout << Name << endl;
}
```

- The Problem with this code is that i want to print the Full Name of
  Name[] array. But it is getting stuck after printing "Hello1" only.
  It is not printing anything after "Hello1". It is taking input of all
  three names ( in First[] , Middle[] and Last[] ) correctly. So, I
  decided to trace out my code from line 1. I got to know that there is
  some problem after first while loop as i am trying to print "Hello1"
  and "Hello2". The problem is that it is printing "Hello1" correctly
  but it is getting stuck for "Hello2". I think that some problem is in
  2nd while loop. But i am not getting the error how could i resolve
  this.

  Please help me regarding this so that it could print the Full Name
  correctly.

Comment: That's probably an [infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218736/stack-overflow-error-vs-infinite-loop). It never leaves the while loop, although I'm not 100% why it wouldn't.

Comment: I am also thinking same , but not getting why.

Comment: Also, I suggest using [std::strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdstring-class-in-c/) instead of `char []` or `char *`. Less chance of making a mistake that way.

Comment: I know that string , but i want to know the reason behind this weird behavior.

Comment: Did you check if there is a character `'\0'` in `last`?

Comment: have you tried running this with a debugger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok so, the problem is your while loop, you made the mistake of put a **;** in the end of it, which is making an infinity loop and never gets to the second hello.

```
//Copies all characters of First name to fourth array
   i = 0;
   while (First[i] != '\0'); // <- Here is your problem
```

**Should be:**

```
//Copies all characters of First name to fourth array
   i = 0;
   while (First[i] != '\0') { // <- Here is your problem
```

#### Edit

Thanks to Gilles-Philippe Paillé who pointed out, in the third while loop also has an semi-colon which should be removed :D

Comment: There is also a semi-colon in the next while loop `while (Middle[i] != '\0');`